# .Net decimal rounding oddities

Tags: .net, decimal, rounding

I'm having the hardest time understanding why the `Math.Round` function in .NET (using framework 4.5) is behaving a certain way:

```
Math.Round(21.4451m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) // 21.45
```

When I call the same with the last decimal place set to 0 instead:

```
Math.Round(21.4450m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) // 21.44
```

**Can someone explain to me why the rounding result is 21.45 on the first example when the last decimal place is 1 or more?**

I need to know as I'm trying to write an algorithm in SQL Server that matches exactly what the .NET framework is doing (since SQL Server uses Arithmetic rounding).

Comment: I don't think SQL server would you ToEven for rounding. In any case if you were rounding to second digit, forth digit would never matter. I won't be considered. Only third digit would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are rounding to 2 decimal places. And you are using [ToEven](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the
>   nearest even number.

Any number **greater than** 21.445 (>21.445) will round to 21.45

And any number **less than or equal to** 21.445 (<=21.445) will round to 21.44.

```
Math.Round(21.44500001m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); //>21.445 therefore 21.45
Math.Round(21.44500000m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); //=21.445 therefore 21.44
Math.Round(21.44499999m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); //<21.445 therefore 21.44
```

It's working correctly. ;)

In order to have the same ROUND behavior as in SQL, use AwayFromZero.

```
SELECT ROUND(21.4451, 2), ROUND(21.4450, 2), ROUND(21.4449, 2)
--less decimal casting, yields:
--     21.4500            21.4500            21.4400

Math.Round(21.44500001m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //21.45
Math.Round(21.44500000m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //21.45
Math.Round(21.44499999m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //21.44
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot now, so obvious. Oh well, thanks anyways :-)

Comment: another pair of eyes can be helpful. :)